# This isn't question and I failed the audit when closing it

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I am confused as to why I failed this [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3623928). I  voted to close it as unclear what you are asking because it's not even a question. It's a statement (and a bit of a complaint about how a language works).

Why should I have voted to keep this question open?

Comment: It's simply a bad audit. I don't know why people upvote these bad questions. It must be because of the hats.. I would have failed it too.

Comment: @JoshC Blame *everything* on the hats! :P

Comment: If you're bothered by the lack of a question mark, you can always edit in a "How would I do that?" at the end.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Hey - [it's true](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211728/how-did-this-answer-manage-to-garner-50-incorrect-not-an-answer-flags-in-less) It wasn't the greatest question either.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Hats. It's *always* hats.

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn What? No no no, we can't change it again! I was *just* getting used to localization :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me as if the OP is asking a "How do I do this in a different language?" question.  He/she posted the Javascript equivalent and is asking for the Lua (Luvit) equivalent.  This should have been left open and edited so that it was more obvious what the user was asking.

At least that's what I'm seeing.  Perhaps Josh's edit made that more evident (looks like it was edited ~12 minutes ago), but that's my guess as to why you failed the audit.

Comment: I was mostly concerned with editing the title. The question being implicit in this case doesn't really bother me, so I didn't add an explicit question phrase.

Answer (score 3):

The system will choose questions that seem to be "good" based on the criteria it has in its software, not based on a human who signed off that this question is really good.  [This question had 5 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20459943/timeline) and no close votes, so it was chosen as an audit question.  Maybe it deserved to be closed, but the system has no way to know that.

See more: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

The good news is that nothing bad happens to you after one failed audit.