# Location of 10K tools filter has no context

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, 10k-tools, filtering

Currently, the "filter by type" options in the side bar under [10K tools](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tools) resembles something like (taken from [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com)):

[image]

The location of these filters seem oddly placed, with no indication that they are meant to be used as filters.

Would it be possible to do one of the following:

- Place them at the top with a description "Filter by type", or
- Update the description of "Where should I start?" to include a reference to the filters. For example:

  > This list is in random order. To see only specific questions based on their flag type, select an item from the filters above/below. Casting any vote type or flagging these posts will cause them to be removed from the list.

  <sub>This might take care of the "list" orphan as well. :)</sub>

Comment: It's easier to just [burn it all with fire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue).

Comment: Those are filters!? I had no idea. I never did think to click them...

Comment: ...this seems to be heading the way of the dodo. As of recent, 10K-tools don't seem to list flags anymore.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a design-requirement that was [recently removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/168244).