# Why can't I comment until I get 50 reputation?

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

Why does Stack Overflow require a contributor to have 50 reputation points before allowing to comment?  I wanted to answer a problem that **many** have in Visual Studio with performance but I can't add my comment. I find it not only annoying that I can't contribute.  Why should I come back and try to help others on this site if I'm not allowed to? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of this site?

Comment: Why don't you add an actual answer?

Comment: And there is no rep limit for answering questions.

Comment: There is whole faq entry for this.

Comment: And this is exactly why I suggested this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226183/135615

Answer (score 4):

> I wanted to answer a problem that MANY have in Visual Studio with performance but I can't add my comment.

If you want to answer the problem, you should be using **answers**, not comments.

Scroll down to the bottom of the page, beyond all the other answers, and find the heading:

### Your Answer

followed by a text box and a big [image: post your answer] button.

Comment: All I see is a void between "big" and "button" ;)

Comment: [shakes fist at whatever may be causing the image to not load]

Comment: (I was poking fun, I can see it just fine)

Comment: [shakes fist at jonsca then in arbitrary other directions]

Comment: I'm glad it's loading after all :D

Comment: The shaking fist was how I thought people greeted each other until I was around 10.

Comment: @jonsca ...it's not? :-P