# Add links to the review history for disputed review auto-flags

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

[Since fairly recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/172958), after a question has gone through a review queue with mixed results, the Community♦ user raises an auto-flag. That flag would be much more helpful if it provided a link to the question's review history (either complete or the queue that triggered the flag).