# 10K Tools let me vote to undelete, but not delete

Tags: support, 10k-tools

I read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue), as it was one of the higher-voted questions about the 10K tools.

I recently got 10K access on Super User, and I've been handling flags whenever I could. I was clicking around, and noticed I get an **undelete** under some of the red posts. Sweet, I have that right... Most posts don't need it though, thankfully.

I read through the Priviliges page though, about the 10K tools, and it said I also had the ability to Vote to Delete posts as well, as long as they're older than 2 days and closed. I've seen flags for VLQ on closed questions from 2011 and 2012, but no link for deleting in the queue. **Is it supposed to be in the queue, or is clicking through to the question the only way to do so?** If we are supposed to click through to the question, why do we need to do that extra step on such old posts?