# 10K Flag review queue shows question link in question

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools

I was going through the Flag queue on Superuser, and got to one question flagged as VLQ. I expand every post so I can get the full picture before acting on it, and I noticed that it copies the link into the question. Just to verify, the URLs are the exact same, but the link does not appear if you open the question manually.

I feel this is a bug. It doesn't help the queue *at all* having the link in with the post this second time. I propose that it gets removed, although it's definitely a low-priority request.

[image]

Comment: Well it looks like they're seriously considering just [getting rid of the whole queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue)...

Comment: I saw that thread, but thought I'd just mention it here, in case it's also in other areas

Answer (score 1):

The same issue appeared in the diamond moderator flag queue, and conveniently both that and this were fixed with the same code change.

Rolling out in revision 2014.4.3.2128 on meta and 2014.4.3.1522 elsewhere.