# Flagged questions: How to indicate I agree with the flag?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

I recently got the power/responsibility to review flagged questions. But the menu offered doesn't have an option of "I'm OK with the flag," thus I get nagged that there are flags to review forever.

Comment: You'd flag the post with the same flag. Some posts will have multiple flags. Do note that the 10k tools are slated to go away.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the latest question that came up had a "Closed w/o comment" flag. Not precisely informative, so it should get another one. OK, which one? It seems I can't leave a comment, bothering the moderators is overkill, ... And "just leave it with the existing flag(s)" (i.e., "skip this one" if you will) isn't an option either).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, hey! what have I been asking/responding my butt off then to get 10k for?!

Comment: See [Let's get rid of the 10K flag queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092)

Comment: @vonbrand To be able to delete questions.

Comment: @vonbrand To help people.

Comment: @vonbrand To be able to delete questions to help people

Comment: I'm asking *how*, not *what for*

Comment: Those previous three comments are all answering the question you asked in [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229469/flagged-questions-how-to-indicate-i-agree-with-the-flag#comment753300_229469), not the question in your question.  In that comment you *did* ask "what for".