# Replace 10k flag count with /tools link

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, top-bar

The 10K tools are still around, just without the flag queue:
[Let's get rid of the 10K flag queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue)

Should we therefore replace the old [image: flags count] flags count with a [image] tools link in the top bar instead?

As it stands, the only way to access /tools is to type it in, or find a link in the privileges description, neither of which seems very intuitive. (Or am I missing another link somewhere which is somehow more intuitive even though I've never seen it?)

Comment: You can get there from [review > tools](https://i.3ventic.eu/1398189124.png), but it would be nice for the review button to be replaced with a drop down like help letting you choose between review and tools - or just add the button.

Comment: Oh look at that! I never saw it. Probably because it's grayed out, and looks like it's the parent in a hierarchy, like Review when you're in Close Votes

Comment: Yeah, it almost fooled me as well.

Comment: As for drop down, my favorite would be to have all the different review categories, with a (live!) number next to each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigating to `/tools` when the blue 42 is not showing doesn't accomplish anything though. When there are no flags, then the tools area is empty for actions.

If your goal is to reach the stats, migrated, close, or delete sections, then you may navigate through the review link

[image]

Then you can click on tools, and select one of the tabs

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yup, I completely missed the more intuitive link. Funny how it wasn't very intuitive to me, but it's plain as day now. As for the flag count, that's apparently gone for good, so that's why I felt so....lost.

Comment: @mhlester - If you missed it you probably were not alone :) UX can be tricky to make everything work intuitively for everyone on the first look.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you did miss a way.

[image: Tools link]

That said, with the old bar the link would sometimes be to tools, and sometimes review. I think it was based on which you had done last; perhaps the new bar could do the same thing.

Comment: We took that behaviour out a ways before the new topbar rolled out, and we're not going back to changing up the links based on last action. That was confusing as all hell.