# Make review link a drop down

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, top-bar, 10k-tools

In the top bar next to the profile is the review link (for users with enough reputation to review). Sometimes this shows suggested edits next to it. Clicking the link opens the /review page, where the queues are shown.

I'm proposing converting the link to a drop-down, similar to the other top bar links (site switcher, inbox, achievements, help).

[image: review drop down]

#### Pros:

- Live counts, unlike the /review page where you have to refresh the whole page to find new items
- Quickly and easily see more counts than just suggested edits, and suggested edits fewer than the current threshold 5.
- For 10K users, easier to find /tools. [*ahem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230228/replace-10k-flag-count-with-tools-link)
- Helps spread out the number of reviews to more people. Currently the review queues are either out of sight and out of mind, or you need to keep another tab open.

#### Cons:

- <del>/review landing page would be hard to access, with the additional information it provides. You would need to access it from within a queue, or show the dropdown on hover, preserving the link to /review on click.</del> (@Raphael's comment solved this perfectly)
- Suggested edit count would feel borderline redundant, but its removal would lead to slower approval on small sites.

Comment: Ad Con #1, it would be possible to add a link "Overview" pointing to `/review` to the dropdown.

Comment: There's [an extension/userscript I made for this on StackApps](http://stackapps.com/questions/4660/review-dropdown-menu)

Comment: Ooh, that's nifty @3ventic. I'll definitely start using this. Are you aware it adds more menu items every time you open the dropdown?

Comment: @mhlester Fixed in 1.6. The version in Chrome web store seems to still be 1.5, I uploaded the fixed version today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now that the [new top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845/162102), the review icon is a drop-down that shows individual queues (color codes, not numbers).  From there, you can click on "all queues" or "tools" to get to the familiar review page or 10k tools.

[image: drop-down list]