# Add basic navigation to New Answers and Suggested Edits in 10k tools

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

There's already a feature request to [add a 10k navigation menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230256/make-review-link-a-drop-down), but this one is simply a couple of links to get back to the main Tools page from "new answers to old questions" and "suggested edit stats".

At the bottom of the main Tools page we have:

> [image: Links on main tools page]

But there's nothing on the interface to get back to the main page, so my suggestion is to add the following links:

> [image: New Answers with Tools button]

and

> [image: Suggested Edit with Tools button]

Answer (score 1):

If by any random chance someone looks for the same, I wrote an userscript to do it. Use [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) or [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) to install it.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    (SE) Missing link on two pages of 10k Mod Tools
// @match    *://OTHER-10k-SITE.stackexchange.com/tools*
// @match    *://*.stackoverflow.com/tools*
// @grant   none
// ==/UserScript==

var the_route = StackExchange.options.routeName;

if( the_route === 'Tools/NewAnswersToOldQuestions' || the_route === 'Tools/SuggestedEdits' ) {
    var text = $('#content .subheader h1').text();
    var html = '<a href="/tools">Tools</a><span class="lsep">|</span><span style="color:#aaa">' + text + '>';
    $('#content .subheader h1').html(html);
}
```