# Make the 10k-tools page more visible

Tags: feature-request, design, 10k-tools

Currently, there are a grand total of **2** pages that link to the [moderator tools page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools) - the [moderator tools privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and the [review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review).

As evidenced by the comments on a [PPCG meta question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11144/45941), a decent number of users don't even know that page exists. I personally never even realized the link was present on the review queue page until it was pointed out:

[image: whaa?!]

The fact that the link is grey doesn't help either - grey doesn't exactly scream "click me!".

Having a link to this page next to the review button on the topbar would make this page massively more visible, and hopefully more users with access to the 10k-tools will make use of the page and its very useful information.

Comment: Maybe it should not be styled as *disabled* if you've the privilege? But IIRC this page is not tailored to a specific user for reasons of performance so that might not be feasible.

Comment: @rene That's also a good point - grey doesn't usually mean "click me!"

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230256/make-review-link-a-drop-down

Comment: @rene: The link is not *shown* to those without 10k. The gray just means it's not the active subset of dedicated moderation tools (that is, conceptually there's a switch between /review and /tools).

Comment: @NathanTuggy ah, yeah. I didn't check on a site where I don't have the privilege.

Answer (score 13):

Thinking about it, I would like to have the link directly in the top bar:

> [image]

This will give the highest possible exposure to the 10k tools.

Answer (score 11):

I've created a userscript to add a button to the omnibar:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Exchange Tools Button
// @version     1.1
// @description A script to add a Tools button to the omnibar on Stack Exchange sites
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @author      Mego
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $(".topbar-menu-links").prepend('<a href="/tools" title="Access moderator tools">tools</a>');
})();
```

Since this is such a simple change, hopefully it won't be too difficult for the SE overlords to implement.

Comment: I like this script :)

Answer (score 2):

To help understand that the reviews are the main thing on that page (this is from the comments, we should change the font color from grey to black and lower the font size of the word just a bit.

Thus would allow users to know that "Tools" isn't part of the set of dedicated moderation tools(thanks Nathan Tuggy) and know that it's clickable.