# Can the new indicator link to /review/all?

Tags: feature-request, review, hyperlinks, top-bar

Well, 10kers have now two links to the review queue, the orange indicator with a total number of items in review and /review. Before these indicators linked to actionable items (flag queue or suggested edits) and I think [some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230228/replace-10k-flag-count-with-tools-link) [of the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230256/make-review-link-a-drop-down) [recent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230874/bring-back-the-suggested-edits-notifications-to-the-top-bar-again) features request are asking for the indicator to be linked to something "actionable". What if instead of being linked to `/review` or `/tools` isn't linked to `/review/all`?

Now, what would be `/review/all`? It will take the most pressing queue in order of importance and redirect you, i.e. there are 30 pending items in the close queue and 5 in the first post, it redirects you to the close queue, and when there isn't anything else actionable it shows you the first posts.

This way we wouldn't have two elements of the UI directing users to a click through page, at the same time that gives the most important review task at the moment.

The order can be by number of pending reviews on each queue, fixed order, or a mix of both. I prefer mixed, being suggested edits the first always, since it should be deal rather quickly and the other queue's by amount of pending tasks.

Comment: I say just pull the entire indicator from big sites. It's totally useless on those sites and always will be.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS The numbers on increased review participation seem to disagree with you there. Too soon to tell long-term, of course, but the initial results are promising.

Comment: @AnnaLear Oh it did a great job telling people there was stuff to review, especially on smaller sites where review is often slow, but on bigger sites the indicator is pretty pointless once you know /review is there. It will *always* be full, of stuff you  can't action on. It totally loses it's value as an indicator. Indicators are supposed to tell you something, provide information you can action on. I already know review is full, so what's the point? The old indicator told me something useful, now it's just a bunch of random numbers that mean nothing to me.

Comment: I guess I'm getting at the fact that there are better ways of notifying people that /review is there and full of stuff. Those of us who actually pay attention to the indicator already know it's full.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Reaching people who already knew it was there and were reviewing was never the goal. We're also open to ideas for better indicators, so if you have some, post them as feature requests.

Comment: @AnnaLear Can I know what the goal was then? It seems a totally ridiculous change if getting more people into review wasn't the goal. I have a couple of ideas floating around in my head, haven't had time to formulate them into anything worth reading though (at least nothing that other people haven't already addressed).

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Err. Getting more people into review *was* the goal. Getting people *who were already reviewing* into review wasn't. I was responding to "on bigger sites the indicator is pretty pointless once you know /review is there" - the key part there is *once you know*. A lot of people don't.

Comment: For an epic fail, it sure seems to be working. :) That said, we're going off on a tangent from this particular proposal.

Comment: @AnnaLear Indeed it is a tangent and I digress. I was going to rephrase my previous comment but I find myself at a lack of words to explain how terrible an idea this was. I'd be interested in seeing some hard stats though.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS I'm aware that Shog will provide them, given time.

Comment: So yeah, @ɥʇǝS - I wanted to wait a few months before publishing anything, since back in May the results looked entirely too good to be true and it's all too tempting to just throw a few numbers out (30% improvement!) and call it a day; what matters is how these things pan out long-term. See my answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236683/how-successful-has-the-review-indicator-been/236727#236727