# Slightly revise the text shown when doing LQP reviews

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts, wording

Now that [the 10k flag queue is no more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/224428) and VLQ and NAA flags feed into the Low Quality Posts queue, it may be worth changing the text shown in that queue from

> This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**.

to

> This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** *or* **content**.

since users need not take into account the length of a post when flagging as VLQ or NAA (but presumably do take into account the content of a post... right?).

I propose this change because the current wording has me slightly on edge whenever I see a long post in the queue - is it a review audit? It must be a review audit. I mean, it looks awful and low quality, but it's *long*. And long posts shouldn't be in this queue, right? The system must be deceiving me. It's a trap!