# Why does this naughty popup want to confuse me?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

As 10k users don't have any special ability to handle flags (since [March 19, 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue)), what does "handle flags" do there?

> [image]

Comment: 10K users can still handle flags in chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, looks like an oversight.

Fixed in the next build, confusing phrasing included.

Answer (score 4):

You are right. According to the [privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), that text should be:

> Access reports, delete questions, review reviews

*'review reviews', confusing... :)*

Comment: Yes, about "review reviews" we posted bugs simultaneously :D