# How am I supposed to "review reviews" once I reach 10k?

Tags: support, privileges

1. [Go to privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/)
2. > [image]

Comment: 3. ??? 4. Profit!

Comment: Amazing how [bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251380/) lead to bugs!

Comment: @Tim [fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/251382/revisions) :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Let moderators navigate the review queues at will](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158239/let-moderators-navigate-the-review-queues-at-will)

Comment: @gnat doesn't look like a dupe...

Comment: "Moderators and 10K users visiting the /history tab for any review queue will, by default, see all recent reviews by all reviewers..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in further detail on [the privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> The full history of reviews by all users in any /review queue

It looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ah I know this feature cuz I already used and use 10k toolz, but didn't know   that phrase mean this :)

Comment: But who reviews the review reviewers? :)