# No need to repeat, I've already hit on it

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Possibly a side-effect of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251380/why-does-this-naughty-popup-want-to-confuse-me) - my next privilege is 10k tools so I see this.

[image]

10,000 rep shouldn't be repeated, I guess.

Comment: You misunderstand - it's ONE HUNDRED million rep.

Comment: so it is missing the multiplication sign. And I've covered half of my distation to... 100m rep? Oh, cool :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too much copy-paste.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Simple mitigation: no more copy-paste for you...