# There are flags in the 10k tools according to the help center

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools, help-center

In the help center, on the [page about reopening questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions), it is stated that:

> How do I find questions that someone thinks should be reopened?
>
> There are two tools to help questions with reopen votes get more attention from users who have the ability to reopen them.
>
> - Review. [...]
> - Tools. Commonly referred to as the "10k tools", this page lets you see even more information - ***certain anonymous flags***, reopen votes, delete votes, etc. The important one for this is the reopen page. Here, you can see questions that might have been closed incorrectly.

(Emphasis mine)

I don't think we can see any (anonymous) flags anymore in the 10k tools.

Comment: Indeed, once upon a time there was a flag queue for 10k users, where they could agree or disagree with flags, helping the moderators a bit. However, it [was removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue) two and half years ago.