# What exactly is meant by "flagged and deleted" in the 10k tools help center article?

Tags: support, status-completed, 10k-tools, help-center

On the topic of deleting questions, the help center article for [Access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) has the following to say, with my emphasis:

> #### When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be **flagged and deleted**.

What exactly is meant by the "flagged" bit? I'm aware of no flag that indicates to other users with this privilege or higher that a question should be deleted. At this stage, as a closed question, the only options available in the flag dialog are...

- **Spam flag** - Not likely that this post is spam if it's closed. It should've just been flag-deleted if that were the case. Even if it were, I'd rather spam-flag-delete than vote to delete.
- **Rude or Abusive flag** - Again, not likely that it deserves to be R/A flagged once it's closed.
- **In Need of Moderator Intervention** - Well that seems a bit over the top, don't you think?

When encountering closed questions of no lasting value, I think the only option is to just vote to delete. So, what exactly does "flagged" in this guidance mean?

I'm aware of what the [10k flag queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291260/622284) was... And I've noticed that there have been some [changes to the guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283456/622284) to reflect that change that weren't caught when it was [removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/622284). Is this an example of some legacy guidance from that time?

Further: Is this something that should be changed?

Comment: It might be referring to the VLQ flag, but in that case, the writer overlooked that that option only shows on open questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no idea. It's been like that since the initial version in 2013, which may have been copied from somewhere else when the new help center was being filled. So who knows how old that text actually is or what reference it was trying to make regarding flags.

I removed the reference to flagging in the line because it clearly does not make sense today.