# Marking questions which are posted as answers as "Looks OK"

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts

Sometimes, while reviewing the **Low Quality Posts** queue, I get 4-5 consecutive answers which are actually a question. And by mistake I think is as a question that needs editing and do the same, marking it **Looks OK** after editing it to a proper format.

What should I do in these cases? As the **history** tab does not have an option to re-judge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, it's clearly indicated if a Low Quality Post is an answer or a question.

[image]

I assume you're reviewing on Stack Overflow, which has an additional Triage review queue; this has the effect that **all** (non-audit) reviews in the Low Quality Posts queue are about answers.

> What should I do in these cases?

Go back to the post and flag it as Not An Answer. If there isn't already a comment indicating that it's not an answer, you should post one (as noted by @Wrzlprmft); just copy the appropriate text from the dialog you see when you click Recommend Deletion (on a next post in the queue). Furthermore, you can hope that the other reviewers will not make the same mistake; each additional active "not an answer" flag causes the review to require [*one more* reviewer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/295232) to choose "Looks OK" to end a Low Quality Posts review.

Note that if you edit a post, that's actually a third option (but implying the post is OK) and submitting the edit will remove the post from the review queue. The post will only go through a review *once*, so a subsequent flag from anyone after a post has already gone through review will go to moderators. If you choose to edit from outside review, the post will go through the system's quality test again (the same one that ordinarily causes posts to automatically enter the LQ queue), and if it passes, it will be removed from the queue.

Comment: I am quite attentive while doing the review tasks. It happens in rare cases, where I get confused while continuously getting only "questions posted as answers".

Comment: You certainly are; otherwise you won't be posting this question :)

Comment: Don’t forget leaving a comment telling the author what is wrong with their post … (CC @AbhishekKeshri)

Comment: "it takes two reviewers" ahem, it takes also 3, if there are at least 2 flags on the post.

Comment: Right, I constantly forget the magic numbers. It's just that the last couple of Looks OK reviews I've seen had two reviewers choosing this option.

Comment: "all (non-audit) reviews"...does that mean that questions sometimes show up as audits there, and as such all questions that show up there are audits?

Comment: Also, it seems like good reason to go through and flag every "recommend deletion" review I made as "not an answer", so that each of those reviews requires one more "Looks OK" review to be removed from the queue.

Comment: @Sonic yes: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289627/4751173